# SQL COUNT() query placement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display all the names of all salespeople that have sold 10 or more orders for the sake of giving them bonuses at the end of the month.

These are my table schema

```
CREATE TABLE Salesperson
(
SalespersonId BIGINT,
Name VARCHAR(50),
BirthDate DATE,
Salary INT
);

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
OrderId BIGINT,
OrderDate DATETIME,
SalespersonId BIGINT,
ProductId BIGINT,
SalesPrice DECIMAL(9,2)
);
```

And then this is my query

```
SELECT Salesperson.Name 
FROM Salesperson
JOIN Orders
ON Salesperson.SalespersonId=Orders.SalespersonId 
WHERE COUNT(Order.SalespersonId)> 10
```

I'm not sure where I should be placing the `COUNT()` function in this to make it return the list of Salesperson names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY`, then use the `HAVING` clause to filter:

```
SELECT Salesperson.Name 
FROM Salesperson
JOIN Orders
ON Salesperson.SalespersonId=Orders.SalespersonId 
GROUP BY Salesperson.Name 
HAVING COUNT(Order.SalespersonId)> 10
```

The predicate used in the `HAVING` clause:

```
COUNT(Order.SalespersonId)> 10
```

is applied to each `Salesperson.Name` group. So it will filter out any groups having a population that is equal to `10` or less.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. `where` is applied at the row level, which means the `count()` result will not be available yet. You have to use `HAVING` instead, which is applied after the full result set has been determined and all aggregate functions have been computed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Salesperson.Name 
FROM Salesperson where Salesperson.SalespersonId in (
SELECT SalespersonId FROM Orders
 GROUP BY SalespersonId and having count(*) > 10 )
```